# Difference between "suave" and "blando"

Tags: selección-de-palabras

When would you use one over the other? I see Google Translate says both equate to "soft" in English.

Comment: Welcome to the site. An upvote to get you going.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"blando" = easy to deform
 "suave" = soft to the tact

"blando" is a property of the body or volume. Its opposite is "duro" or "rígido".

"suave" is a property of the surface. Its opposite is "áspero".

A piece of rubber, or a mattress, is "blando"

A kitten fur is "suave".

Muscles are "blandos", skins are "suaves".

"blando" can be also applied to semi-liquids materials (thin, as opposed to thick ; eg: honey). 
Furthermore, both have many analogous uses:
"blando" can be used for a maleable personality;
"suave" can mean soft to the ear ("música suave"), etc

Comment: I love the breadth of examples and also the fact that you listed their opposites. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In social terms, "suave" implies "smooth." That's a positive kind of "soft."

"Blando" implies weak or "wimpy." That's a negative kind of "soft."

Comment: The song "Rico Blando" is one of my favourites.